# Can WordPress plugins W3 Cache, Autoptimize, Stackpath CDN, and Shortpixel be used together?

Tags: wordpress, cdn, optimization, plugin, image-hosting

I'm trying to combine some WordPress plugins to speed up my websites. Can I use

- W3 Cache
- Autoptimize
- a CDN with Stackpath,
- Shortpixel Image Optimization

together at the same time? Are there any settings within each plugin that need to be adapted so they work with each other?